# querySelectorAll alternative for vuejs nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I am currently using

```
var images = Array.from(this.$refs["dynaContent"].querySelectorAll("img"));
```

It works on the webpage but terminal shows error log with

```
ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined"
```

[image]

I want to target all img tags inside div with dynacontent ref, div with .dynamic-content class

Comment: Make sure `this.$refs["dynaContent"]` has a value at the momnent you executung `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

adding if(process.client) fixes it.